# Is it possible to display a fixed string before an input box in a Ionic v3 alert?

Tags: ionic3, alert

I have an input alert that collects the amount of money that was spent on a certain task and it looks like this:

**Input alert:**
[image: Input alert]

The input only accepts numbers and the "R$" in the placeholder is a type of currency and what I would like to do is move it outside of the input box and make it a fixed string so that the user can type in the number and the currency signs still shows up there, somewhat like this:

**Desired input alert:**
[image: Desired input alert]

Is it possible to do that and if so how do I do it?

The code for the current alert is as it follows:

```
costAlert(task) {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Execution cost',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'cost',
        placeholder: "R$ " + "150.00",
        type: 'number'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          // return false
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: data => {
          console.log("Save pressed: ")
          task.cost = data.cost
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

---

Comment: Include your current code in the post. If you've tried to solve the problem but have been unsuccessful so far, also mention what you've tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on how to best ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't think the code would be relevant to the question because it's just the standard ionic alert but ok, I will edit the question with the code